# Representing an IS A relationship in a SQL database

Tags: database-design

Let's say I want to store information about several persons in an database. Every person can have no, one or more roles. Each role has some attributes like a name, number and so on (the roles have different attributes).

In my opinion this relationship between a Person and a Role can be described as "IS A". Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see how colloquial English (or ESL) might indicate that a person indeed "is" a job role. However, you're dealing with a system of possibilities and ownership rather than the fact that, at least Americans, like to reduce a person's existence to their career role.

"She is a police officer" - works during standard conversation.

"He has a role of police officer" - reflects the possibility of no, one, or more roles that [a person may own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a). You're dealing with composition not subtyping.

`CREATE TABLE` is one of the most basic aspects of SQL... you're only hurting yourself if you don't take the time to actually learn the language. Here's one [good starting resource](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_create_table.asp). Your next step will likely be to add a `Foreign Key` constraint.